# Recovering photos from a formatted drive on Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery

I installed Ubuntu on an old computer I had, which ran Vista. I choose to do a clean install of Ubuntu over the entire HDD. Later on I found out that there were old precious photos on that HDD. Is there anyway to recover these photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) is the best tool for recovering pictures from a deleted partition.

PhotoRec is file data recovery software designed to recover lost files including video, documents and archives from hard disks, CD-ROMs, and lost pictures (thus the Photo Recovery name) from digital camera memory. PhotoRec ignores the file system and goes after the underlying data, so it will still work even if your media's file system has been severely damaged or reformatted.

Comment: At least for recovered pictures you can restore their filenames using the date and time properties within their EXIF data (if present). I've explained how to do it [here](https://superuser.com/a/1703412/109947).